# How to retrieve data from the mysql database using prepared statement in php?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

```
<?php
    require "config.php";
    if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM donorregistration WHERE Email=? and Password=?")) 
    {
        $email=$_POST['donorEmail'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $stmt -> bind_param("ss",$email,$password);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows!=1)
        {
            echo "Sorry, Your E-mail ID or Password is incorrect";
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    $mysqli -> close();
?>
```

I dont know what to write in the else part.  I want to print the column named "Account_Number" and the column "Name" from mysql database. Please help me.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: It's great you're using prepared statements, but **plaintext passwords** are an extremely bad idea. Please follow best practices for [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) so you don't recklessly endanger your users.

Comment: Mr. Hanky Panky and Tadman. Thank you both for your kind help.  I retrieved the required data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

use the **fetch** and **bind_result** statements to retrieve data

Try this below

```
<?php
require "config.php";
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM donorregistration WHERE Email=? and Password=?")) 
{
    $email=$_POST['donorEmail'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $stmt -> bind_param("ss",$email,$password);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($email,$pass);
    $stmt->fetch();
    if($stmt->num_rows!=1)
    {
        echo "Sorry, Your E-mail ID or Password is incorrect";
    }
    else
    {
        //retrieved 
       echo "Your email is $email and pass $pass");
    }
}
$mysqli -> close();
```

?>